# Chrome extension, how to track each visited page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-addon, google-chrome-app

I wanted to build a Google Chrome extension that would display domain popularity, the way Alexa domain stats did;

I am able to display any data inside popup.html when user clicks my extension button (to show domain rank, backlinks, etc) but in background I need to track popular urls visited by users.

Using manifest v3, I was able (inside `background.js`) to detect and trigger code on each url change, but I cannot find a function that would allow the extension to ping my servers in order to tell what url/domain is visited by user.

I assume best way to do this is to make an URL get request in background. How can I do something like that ? Basically I want the extension to send a text message to an url of mine.

Comment: Use the built-in `fetch`

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do it simply with `fetch(my_url);` as I can't get the provided `fetch` examples to work. The documentation is killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wOxxOm mentioned you can use built in fetch API. As mentioned in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) documentation, you can use fetch like this -

```
fetch(your_url, fetchParams) //fetch returns promise, that resolves to a response object
.then(response => response.json()) //assuming JSON response
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

where fetchParam is typically a javascript object that follows the documentation mentioned above. you can add your custom data in the fetchParam's body key. like this

```
fetchParam = {
                method: your_metod,
                headers: your_header_object,
                body: your_data
            };
```

Hope I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Yes, that seems to do what I need. Can you please tell me how to use the variable `data` outside of that "arrow function" ? If I try to access `data` after this code, it is undefined.

Comment: got, it, it can be passed to a user defined function with `.then(data => process_fetch_data(data))`